# package junit.framework does not exist api 28

Tags: android, gradle, junit, assert

For a project using `api 27` the build was successful. After moving to `api 28` I am getting the following error. Please could you let me know why this occurs in `api 28` and how I should fix my project?

```
error: package junit.framework does not exist
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
error: cannot find symbol variable Assert
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the imports from the file which is generating the error? Also the dependancies section of your `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Android API Differences Report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/28/changes/changes-summary), `junit.framework` package is removed since API 28.

You may need to declare the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // or implementation 'junit:junit:4.12' when not in test environment
}
```